# Append characters based on the count of a match in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

I would like to append - at the end of each word match. But, the number of - appended should be based on the count of the match, so that the total number of characters in that line remain constant.

As shown in the example below, the total number of characters should be 6.

e.g.

```
ab
xyz
abcde
```

The above text should be replaced to:

```
ab----
xyz---
abcde-
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if there is a notepad++ solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\=` to substitute with an expression, see `:h sub-replace-expression`.

> When the substitute string starts with `\=`, the remainder is interpreted as an expression.
>
> The `submatch()` function can be used to obtain matched text. The whole matched text can be accessed with `submatch(0)`. The text matched with the first pair of `()` with `submatch(1)`. Likewise for further sub-matches in `()`.

So you can achieve it like this:

```
:[range]s//\=submatch(0) . repeat('-', 6-strlen(submatch(0)))/
```

Comment: `repeat({exp}, {count})` returns nothing if `{count}` is less than or equal to zero, so you can simplify this by eliminating the check: `:[range]s/.*/\=submatch(0) .. repeat('-', 6 - strlen(submatch(0)))`.

Comment: @romainl Thanks for your review. I revised the answer, now it's more concise.