regex in vim: how can I replace `+` expanded characters
I am trying to replace all leading occurrences of = with #.
=
lorem
==
ipsum
====
foo=bar

Ususally I would do something like this.
:%s/^====/####/g
:%s/^===/###/g
:%s/^==/##/g
:%s/^=/#/g

Not nice, but gets the job done.
My startng point is :%s/^\(=+\)/#/g, but this would turn all leading occurences of = into a single #.
Two appoaches I have in mind, but don't know how to implement are:

have all occurences of = replaced within the capture group.
determine the length of the capture group and .

Is there a way to solve this in a regex vim one-liner?

Using \=submatch() and repeat() like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75280575/7976758

You can use the :global command to find lines that start with an equals sign and then use the :substitute's g flag to replace every =:
:g/^=/s/=/#/g

See :help :g and :help :s_g.

Thanks! neat and sufficient for my presented test case!
But when extending it by introducing a line = foo: x=y this would also replace the second =.

Different question, different answer. The idea is to use the most simple thing that works for your buffer. In your extended case, you can either undo select replacements, use the c flag to confirm each operation or use one of the other answers. It depends on the number of matches and the their ratio.

Using \=, submatch() and repeat():
:%s/^\(=\+\)/\=repeat('#', strlen(submatch(0)))/

Replace runs of = (at the start of the line) by the same number of #.

You can use a lookbehind in Vim, it supports unknown width patterns inside it:
:%s/\(^=*\)\@<==/#/g

Here:

\(^=*\)\@<= - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with start of a string (here, a line) and then zero or more = symbols.
= - a = symbol.

